# Как обрабатывать сразу несколько списков?

Tags: python, discord.py

Есть бот крестики-нолики в дискорде. Как создавать и обрабатывать сразу несколько досок для игры?

Comment: Сохранять состояния для каждого пользователя отдельно?

Comment: Да, примерно так. Только там два игрока в одной игре

Comment: Тогда сохраняйте состояние доски для пар игроков

Comment: Извините, не могли бы вы дать ссылку на пример того, как это сделать

Comment: Было бы неплохо увидеть ваш код, так как угадать как вы это реализовали вряд ли удастся ))) Как пример гляньте [здесь](https://github.com/HizkiFW/discord-tictactoe)

Comment: Вот именно поэтому я здесь, а пока что бот поддерживает только одну игру

Comment: Спасибо за пример, понял что нужно делать